# SharePoint 2016 Search just working on server

Tags: sharepoint, administration

I have problem with SharePoint search , its working inside server but when i try search out of server (from domain) Sorry, something went wrong.

all settings is fine .

can any one help plz ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using SharePoint search within the in server and outside the server the URL's are same? do following steps as well:

- Check for the crawl Logs
- Delete Search Services and Recreate it again
- Check the user permission, check with the Farm Admin / Site collection Admin
- Check Firewall, Port, antivirus might be they are blocking it
- Check for other different or new site collections search results

Comment: Yes , the problem from Firewall (F5)